# How to test document clicks in unit tests in angular

Tags: angular, testing

We have a drop-down component that has its dropdown collapsed on any outside click.
This is implemented as:

```
  @HostListener('document:click', ['$event'])
  public documentClick(event) {
    if (this.dropdownIsOpen && !event.clickedFromMe) {
      this.dropdownIsOpen = false;
    }
  }
```

How can this code be tested? When using `TestBed.createComponent`, only the component seems to be created, and it is not inside any document, so how can I simulate a click outside of that component?

Comment: Post the test code as well

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Use `document.dispatchEvent`:

```
 it('should handle document click', () => {
    component.dropdownIsOpen = true;
    document.dispatchEvent(new MouseEvent('click'));
    expect(component.dropdownIsOpen).toBe(false);
  });
```

Answer (score 2):

It **is** inside a document.

Just use

```
const compiled: HTMLElement = fixture.nativeElement;
compiled.ownerDocument.dispatchEvent(new Event('click'));
```

An alternative if to create a fixture for a test component which uses your component in its template, and also some sibling button, for example, and to click on this sibling button.